# Can't run a script

Tags: shell-script, path

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I figured out the terminal uses the `.bashrc` file.  I added:

```
export PATH="/home/keaton/scripts/:$PATH"
```

to that file then created a script in the `scripts` directory.  The simple script is:

```
echo "Hello World"
echo $(which neqn)
cat $(which neqn)
```

when I go into the terminal and run `sh intro` I get:

```
sh: 0: Can't open intro
```

I've triple checked that the path to the `scripts` directory is typed out correctly.  Is there something I'm typing or configuring incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `sh` trying using `bash`. This works for me:

```
$ bash intro
Hello World
/usr/bin/neqn
#! /bin/sh
# Provision of this shell script should not be taken to imply that use of
# GNU eqn with groff -Tascii|-Tlatin1|-Tutf8|-Tcp1047 is supported.

GROFF_RUNTIME="${GROFF_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin}:"
PATH="$GROFF_RUNTIME$PATH"
export PATH
exec eqn -Tascii ${1+"$@"}

# eof
```

When you invoke your script using `sh` you're actually using `bash` but it's running in a mode which makes it behave as if it's a more ancient version of the shell that is the predecessor to Bash.

*excerpt from `man bash`*:

> ```
>  If  bash  is  invoked  with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup 
>  behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while 
>  conforming to the POSIX standard as well.  When invoked as an interactive 
>  login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first 
>  attempts to read and execute commands from /etc/profile and ~/.profile, 
>  in that order. The  --noprofile option may be used to inhibit this 
>  behavior.  When invoked as an interactive shell with the name sh, bash 
>  looks for the variable ENV, expands its value if it is defined,
>  and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.  
>
>  Since a shell invoked as sh does not attempt to read and execute  
>  commands  from  any  other  startup  files,  the --rcfile  option  has no 
>  effect.  A non-interactive shell invoked with the name sh does not 
>  attempt to read any other startup files.  When invoked as sh, bash enters 
>  posix mode after the startup files are read.
> ```